# Melee System errors (Unityscript)

Tags: system, unityscript

Hi I'm new to coding and have been having problems with this code for months. No matter what I do there always seems to be an error that consistently pops up. Please help.

```
#pragma strict

var damage : int = 1;

var distance : float; 

function update ()   
{ 
     var hit : raycasthit;    
     if (physics.raycast ( transform.position, transform.transformdirection ( vector3.forward , hit ); ); 

     {distance = hit.distance; hit.transform.sendmessage ( "applydamage" , damage , sendmessageoptions.dontrequirereceiver); }; 
};
```

Comment: Can you show us what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Ok so I changed a few things but now I have error BCE 0044 on line 16. It says that it wants } but when I put it in the error doesn't go away. but when I put it in I get an error BCE 0020 and BCE 0019.

#pragma strict

var damage : int = 1;
var distance : float; 

function update ()   
{ 
                   var hit = Transform.TransformDirection ( Vector3.forward);
                   if (Physics.Raycast( transform.position, hit ))
       {
        distance = hit.distance; 
        gameObject.SendMessage( "applydamage" , damage);
    ;
                   };
                   };

Comment: Please try my sample code below.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many syntax and name errors.

First of all i think you should learn basics of programming and after that spesific language syntax then platform libraries.

2, [SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver.html)

3, [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) parameters are incorrect.

4, `TransformDirection`

5, `RaycastHit`

6, `SendMessage`

7, [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

Maybe below is more clean

```
#pragma strict

var damage : int = 1;   
var distance : float;

function Update (){ 
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast( transform.position, transform.TransformDirection ( vector3.forward) , hit ){
        distance = hit.distance; 
        hit.transform..SendMessage( "applydamage" , damage , SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    };
};
```

And also please always look [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html) for understanding logic and resolving syntax errors.